ASP.NET Web API execution halt on exception despite catching the exception in an async call whose completion is awaited using Result and Wait
I am facing an issue in my ASP.NET Web API where an exception thrown in the method which is used to send an async POST to an API, even though I have a try-catch block surrounding the method call which has logged the exception.
My question is even if exception is occurred, which caught by try-catch block around the method call which is logging the exception, why is execution halted and why it does not go with the flow after logging exception?
The code and exception occurred are below:
public bool PostData(string ApiURL, object data, out string resp)
{
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiURL);
            var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync("", data);
            responseTask.Wait(); // Blocking call

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            var success = result.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            readTask.Wait(); // Blocking call
            resp = readTask.Result;

            return success;
        }
    }
}


Exception Message : The remote name could not be resolved:


I don't see any try..catch in your code?

Ultimately, using .Wait() here is just wrong; that's an incorrect way of using this API. Is that related to what you're seeing? We can't really say, not least because you haven't included the try/catch. Note that Wait() even on a pre-completed task can have different fault semantics to .GetAwaiter().GetResult() (specifically relating to AggregateException) but - and I cannot emphasize this enough - the correct usage here is await

I have refactored your code little bit. For working this sample code install "Newtonsoft.Json" plugin from NuGet package manager.
async Task<(bool,string)> PostDataNew(string ApiURL, object data)
{
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            try
            {
                // Send POST request
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(ApiURL, content);

                // Check if the response is successful
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Read response content as string
                    string resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return (true,resp);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.StatusCode);
                    return (false,"");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return (false,"");
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Instead of using Wait(), when you are making POST call use await, Same while reading the response of the request that will eliminate the use of Wait() and Result
